# Why is $\int\frac{\sin (3\theta + \pi )+14}{15} \times \frac{\sin (3\theta - \pi )+14}{15}\,d\theta$ near double the area of $r=1$ with area $\pi?$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

How is $$\int\frac{\sin (3\theta + \pi )+14}{15} \times \frac{\sin (3\theta - \pi )+14}{15}\,d\theta$$ almost double the area of $r=1$ with area $\pi?$

This is the graph of the function 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6q7fprhqak

This is plugged into integral calculator
[This is it plugged into integral calculator](http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-3/multiple-double-triple-integral-calculator/?f=%28%28%20sin%20%281*%20theta%20%29%2B14%29%2F15%29*%28%28%20sin%20%281*%20theta%20%29%2B14%29%2F15%29&b=r%2C0%2C1%3Btheta%2C0%2C2%20pi)

This must be a mistake. I am not sure why my integration is wrong though

Comment: First of all $\sin(3\theta+\pi)=\sin(3\theta-\pi)$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Whatever gets multiplied with $theta$ and also the phase shift doesn't seem to matter. When you integrate from r:0-1 ; $theta$:0-2$pi$ I get $(131/75)*pi$

Comment: Austin, write \theta with a dollar sign at the start and end to create $\theta$. Do the same for Pi with \pi instead. A "*multiplication sign*" can be expressed as \times with a dollar sign also at the start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta)\,d\theta$$ is not the area of the curve, even when $f(\theta)>0$ for all $\theta$. This is because for $\Delta\theta$, the area is estimated by a triangle, not a rectangle. In particular, you have a triangle with lengths $f(\theta),f(\theta+\Delta \theta)$ and angle $\Delta\theta$. The triangle area is thus 
$$\frac{1}{2}f(\theta)f(\theta+\Delta\theta)\sin \Delta\theta.$$

Turns out, $\sin\Delta x\sim \Delta x$ is good enough. Thus, to get the area bounded by $f(\theta)$, you want:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}2f(\theta)^2\,d\theta$$

So you get a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, plus you want to square your function.

It's a little trickier of $f(\theta)$ is negative for some values $\theta$.

See: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx

Comment: Ok that makes much more sense! Thankyou!